# Добротный дизайн

Tags: html, вёрстка

Добротный дизайн - это только фон, шапка и разметка статей, меню для сайта? Или еще что-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это удобство пользованием конечным продуктом. дизайн -- это не "рисуночки" с "эффектиками", это визуальное, техническое, эргономическое решение задачи.

*покормил*

Answer (score 1):

Это очень сложно - смотря что считать добротным. Некоторые дизайнеры делают так, что и самый минималистичный дизайн выглядит красиво и со вкусом, а бывает и самые нагруженные(в графическом плане) сайты резво отрисовываются, мало весят и радуют глаз.
По моему мнению, главное - это точно соотнести юзабилити и графику, чтобы было эргономично.
http://www.premiumpixels.com/ - как пример